# Implicit operator & generic class

Tags: c#

Why does this C# code cannot compile ?

```
public class X
{ }

public class Xi : X
{
    public int I { get; }
    public Xi(int i) { I = i; }
    public static implicit operator Xi(int i) { return new Xi(i); }
}

public class L<T> : X where T : X
{
    public L(params T[] values) { }
}

public static void Main()
{
    var test1 = new L<Xi>(1, 2, 3); // OK
    var test2 = new L<Xi>(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }); // Unable to convert int[] into Xi
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Arrays are not implicitly casted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your working example:

```
var test1 = new L<Xi>(1, 2, 3);
```

C# is able to determine that each *element* of the `params` is of type `Xi`. Thus, the generated code is equivalent to

```
var test1 = new L<Xi>(new Xi[] { 1, 2, 3 });
```

Here, each `int` is implicitly cast to `Xi`, and thus your code works. *However*, with this code:

```
var test2 = new L<Xi>(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 });
```

You're explicitly passing an `int[]` rather than a `Xi[]`. As [Wazner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5082427/wazner) points out in the comments, arrays are not implicitly (or explicitly, in this case) castable.

Answer (score 2):

Although new instance of `Xi` can be initialized with `int` value, array of `int` can not be initialized as array of `Xi`.

```
//initializing array of Xi, so for each value constructor of Xi called
Xi[] a = new Xi[] { 1, 2, 3 }; //works
//array of int is not array of Xi
Xi[] b = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }; //fails
//1, 2, 3 are integers and anonymous array initializes as int[]
Xi[] c = new[] { 1, 2, 3 }; //fails
```

[Array covariance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664572(v=vs.71).aspx) works only for reference types and in the inheritance hierarchy:

```
Xi[] a = new Xi[] { 1, 2, 3 };
object[] b = a; //works good
```

`int` is not reference type and `int` does not inherits from `Xi`, it can be only casted to `Xi`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public L(params T[] values) { }
public L(IEnumerable<T> values) { }
```

If we define a type like `T` we should give a suitable `type` as parameter. Writing `Xi` is OK instead of `int`.

```
var test2 = new L<Xi>(new Xi[] { 1, 2, 3 });
```

Comment: The overloaded constructor has no bearing here - the code compiles only because of the second snippet (explicitly constructing a `Xi` array rather than an `int` array)

Answer (score 0):

You have defined a converter for `int` => `Xi` but this does not give you a converter from `int[]` to `Xi[]`

```
var test3 = new L<Xi>(new Xi[] { 1, 2, 3 });
```

works because each of the `int`s are converted to `Xi`s and then the Xi[] is passed into the ctor.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `array` Cast:

Your code is:

```
public L(params T[] values) { }
```

and your call is:

```
var test1 = new L<Xi>(1, 2, 3); // OK
```

1,2,3 can be cast to `int` because `Xi(int i)`.

On the other hand:

```
var test2 = new L<Xi>(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 });
```

is an `Array` of `int`, so you can solve this of several forms:

- Add a new parameter in `L<T>`

```
public L(params int[] values) { }
```

- Overload `Xi`, this form need other `array` property like example:

```
public class Xi : X
{
  public int I { get; }
  public int[] Other { get; }
  public Xi(int i) { I = i; }
  public Xi(int[] i) { Other = i; }
  public static implicit operator Xi(int i) { return new Xi(i); }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to put the method definition into a class/struct definition. Method definitions can't appear outside those.

```
   public class X
{ }

public class Xi : X
{
    public int I { get; }
    public Xi(int i) { I = i; }
    public static implicit operator Xi(int i) { return new Xi(i); }
}

public class L<T> : X where T : X
{
    public L(params T[] values) { }

   public static void Main()
   {
       var test1 = new L<Xi>(1, 2, 3); // OK
       var test2 = new L<Xi>(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }); // Unable to convert int[] into Xi
   }
}
```

Comment: Obviously it could be nested classes in the `Program` or simply different parts of code. It is not a problem OP searching the solution for. Your code clearly conflicts with author's intent.